# How split paragraph into Lines in R language

Tags: r

I'm beginner of R , Learning the basic things 
Trying to retrieve sentences which contains some specific word
I read file data using readLines() and using grep trying to retrieve some specific sentences
But the data retrieved is complete paragraph that contains the specific word

```
x<- readLines(filepath)
grep("processor",x,value=TRUE,ignore.case=TRUE)
```

If my word is "processor" then complete paragraph that contains processor is retrieved

output :
A 5th Gen Corei3 processor, 8GB RAM, 2GB graphics processor, 1TB HDD, 15.6-inch 720p HD antireflective display, this laptop is a premium offering in this segment. Coming from a brand like HP this offers you the status value and corporate services that you might need while conducting business.

But i want only single sentence
i.e  A 5th Gen Corei3 processor, 8GB RAM, 2GB graphics processor, 1TB HDD, 15.6-inch 720p HD antireflective display, this laptop is a premium offering in this segment.

How to split paragraph into lines . so that I can get only sentences that contains specific word and is grep good to use or not

Comment: We don't have text to help you with. This is not a minimal, working, reproducible example and will likely get closed.

Comment: Adding to @hrbrmstr comment - please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `quanteda` package can be used to tokenize the text input into sentences. Once the documents are separated into sentences, `grep()` can be used to extract the sentences containing the word *processor* into a vector.  We'll use a raw text file that gets interpreted as 2 documents in quanteda, and extract the sentences containing the word *processor*.

```
rawText <- "A 5th Gen Core i3 processor, 8GB RAM, 2GB graphics processor, 1TB HDD, 15.6-inch 720p HD antireflective display, this laptop is a premium offering in this segment. Coming from a brand like HP this offers you the status value and corporate services that you might need while conducting business.
Intel® Celeron® processor N3160. Entry-level quad-core processor for general e-mail, Internet and productivity tasks. 4GB system memory for basic multitasking: Adequate high-bandwidth RAM to smoothly run multiple applications and browser tabs all at once."

library(quanteda)
sentences <- tokens(rawText,"sentence")
unlist(lapply(sentences,function(x){
     grep("processor",x,value=TRUE)
}))
```

...and the output:

```
> unlist(lapply(sentences,function(x){
+      grep("processor",x,value=TRUE)
+ }))


text11 

"A 5th Gen Core i3 processor, 8GB RAM, 2GB graphics processor, 1TB HDD, 15.6-inch 720p HD antireflective display, this laptop is a premium offering in this segment." 


text12 


"Intel® Celeron® processor N3160." 


text13 


"Entry-level quad-core processor for general e-mail, Internet and productivity tasks." 
>
```

Another approach is to use `stringi::str_detect_fixed()` to find the strings.

```
# stringi::stri_detect_fixed() approach 
library(stringi)
unlist(lapply(sentences,function(x){
      x[stri_detect_fixed(x,"processor")]
}))
```

Comment: Yeah , Thanks for your help