# Separate into sentences

Tags: r

I used readLines to import a text file and I collapsed all the lines. Now I want to write a function that would cycle through the entire collapsed text and detect the end of each sentence starting a new line for each sentence. It would detect (periods, question marks, periods followed by quotations, or question marks followed by quotations)

so for example:

```
"I need help. How do I write this code?"
```

would become:

```
I need help.
How do I write this code?
```

Does anyone know how I might go about accomplishing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994530/how-split-paragraph-into-lines-in-r-language

Answer (score 1):

gsub might work.

```
gsub('. ', '.\n', your_text)
```

replaces the `'. '` pattern by `'\n '` which is the symbol for a line break.

```
your_text = 'lets. try'
aa = gsub('. ', '.\n', your_text)
print(aa)
cat(aa)
```

Comment: I tried this but instead of creating a new line it replaced every period with an actual ".\n"

Comment: I think it is because you need to output ti using the cat function

Answer (score 0):

We can use positive look behind regex to match for a `"."` or a question mark `"?"` and replace it with new line (`\n`).

```
str = "I need help. How do I write this code? "
cat(gsub('(?<=[.?])\\s', '\n', str, perl = TRUE))

#I need help.
#How do I write this code?
```